# Optimize Select Distinct

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

Here is the problem:

This is some sample data:

```
cats=# select * from cats limit 8;
   id    | color |  breed  
---------+-------+---------
 4380929 | grey  | persian
 4380930 | grey  | siese
 4380931 | white | persian
 4380932 | white | siamese
 4380933 | grey  | persian
 4380934 | grey  | siese
 4380935 | white | persian
 4380936 | white | siamese
(8 rows)
```

Here is how to construct the database:

```
psql postgres postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE cats;"
psql cats postgres -c 'CREATE SEQUENCE cat_id_seq;'
psql cats postgres -c "CREATE TABLE cats (id BIGINT NOT NULL default nextval('cat_id_seq'), color text, breed text);"
bash -c 'for i in `seq 1 1000000` ; do echo -e "white\tpersian\nwhite\tsiamese\ngrey\tpersian\ngrey\tsiese"; done;' > /tmp/cats.sql
psql cats postgres -c "COPY cats (color, breed) FROM /tmp/cats.sql"
```

And this is the query:

```
psql cats postgres -c "select distinct((color,breed)) from cats;"
```

Running this query takes for me:

```
 Unique  (cost=783138.21..805138.22 rows=6 width=12) (actual time=69816.259..81338.631 rows=5 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=783138.21..794138.22 rows=4400001 width=12) (actual time=69816.258..80412.546 rows=4400001 loops=1)
     Sort Key: (ROW(color, breed))
     Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 189456kB
     ->  Seq Scan on cats  (cost=0.00..72026.01 rows=4400001 width=12) (actual time=0.013..846.713 rows=4400001 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 81363.373 ms
(6 rows)
```

Output:

```
(grey,persian)
(grey,siamese)
(grey,siese)
(white,persian)
(white,siamese)
(5 rows)
```

Do you know how I can make this fast?

This would work, but only for one attribute, not for two, as is this case: http://zogovic.com/post/44856908222/optimizing-postgresql-query-for-distinct-values

I think I need an index on '(color, breed)' and then:

- Create a temporary table TEMP (color, breed)
- Insert into TEMP (select (color, breed) from cats where (color, breed) not in TEMP)
- Until there are no more to insert...
- Select * from TEMP

But I don't know exactly how to write that on postgres (without lots of bakery) - should I use RECURSIVE? or plpgsql?

Thanks!

Comment: The execution plan looks fine. Probably, you should optimize the sort operation. Give it more memory so that it does not have to spill to disk. 81sec to sort just 4m rows is a little much.; Or, force HashAggregate to be used which seems like a good idea because the number of groups is so small.

Comment: Running *which* query? The `COPY`? An index cannot help with that, on the contrary. But the `EXPLAIN` output is for a different query, not in your question ... I suspect you want a solution like [this one](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62598/select-specified-number-of-unique-ids-where-second-column-is-unique/62616#62616) or [this one](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61173/self-join-unique-pairs/61237#61237).

Comment: You're totally right, it was a typo, I fixed the question now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So, after much work, here goes the solution:

First - create the index:

```
create index ON cats (color,breed);
```

First: the simple query:

```
cats=# select distinct color,breed from cats;
       row       
-----------------
 (a,b)
 (c,d)
 (grey,persian)
 (grey,siamese)
 (grey,siese)
 (white,persian)
 (white,siamese)
(7 rows)

Time: 853.550 ms
```

**Now the version you want to use:**

```
WITH RECURSIVE distinct_pairs AS (
    (
        SELECT c as cl FROM cats c where color IS NOT NULL AND breed IS NOT NULL order by c.color,c.breed LIMIT 1
    )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT (
        SELECT c
        FROM cats c
        WHERE
            (c.color,c.breed) > ((p.cl).color,(p.cl).breed)
        ORDER BY c.color,c.breed LIMIT 1
    )
    FROM distinct_pairs p
    WHERE (p.cl).id IS NOT NULL
) SELECT * FROM distinct_pairs p WHERE (p.cl).id IS NOT NULL;
         cl          
---------------------
 (4400007,a,b)
 (5,grey,persian)
 (6,grey,siamese)
 (400006,grey,siese)
 (2,white,persian)
 (4,white,siamese)
(6 rows)

Time: 0.646 ms
```

1300x faster. Not bad.

Thanks to:

- http://www.depesz.com/2014/01/29/getting-count-of-distinct-elements-per-group-in-postgresql/ and
- http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have the parentheses?  Do you know what they do, and do you need that?

I get about twenty times faster if I drop them:

```
select distinct color, breed from cats;
```

Wrapping the columns up into records, and then unpacking the records for every sort comparison, is a lot of work.

Comment: Yep, you're totally right, it was much faster that way for me also. But it can still be much improved (see my answer).